# Find all columns in datatable and also IDs

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a table Adapter that search in my database and return rows with `StatusValue == false`.

Now I want to delete those rows. How can I do that in C#?

My code in c#:

```
DataSet.TableDataTable TableDT = new DataSet.TableDataTable();
DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter TableTA = new DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();

TableTA.FillByUserStatus(TableDT, false);
// Here I want to delete rows in my database by IDs;
```

My SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] 
(
    [UserID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [firstname]      NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [lastname]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [field]          NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [number]         NCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
    [email]          NCHAR (50)     NULL,
    [Ordered Amount] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Description]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ReservationStatus] BIT NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Why are you getting the rows out of the database to the application if you are just going to delete them? Why dont you just issue a `delete from where ...` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the datatable, it's easy to remove rows

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Fill the data table with rows 

var rows = dt.DefaultView;
rows.RowFilter = "your condition";
for (var i = 0; i <= rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Remove(rows[i].Row);
}
```

If you used EF, things would be easy from C# using LINQ. To find all columns from the table, you need to know the table meta data.

Answer (score 0):

As CodingYoshi said in the comments, it doesn't make sense to load rows into a table and delete them one by one. That will be exponentially slower. Pass a command to the database like below:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private void DeleteStuff()
{
   string sql = "delete from MyTable where StatusValue = 0";
   string myConnectionString = "<connection string goes here>";
   CreateCommand(sql, myConnectionString);
}
```

If you have time, I'd suggest reading up on ORMs and stored procedures.